# Linux shell script for counting similar words in a file

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

Am having a log file in following format:

```
201208290101
201208290101
201208290101
201208290101
201208290101
201208291222
201208291222
201208291222
201208291222
201209300242
201209300242
201209300242
```

i want to count the number of events occurred at some particular time so i have to count 
how many times some particular time stamp occurred in log file . for example output of the above would be something like :

```
201208290101  = 5
201208291222  = 4
201209300242  = 3
```

any suggestion on how to count this  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pipe the file through `uniq -c`.

```
$ uniq -c
201208290101
201208290101
201208290101
201208290101
201208290101
201208291222
201208291222
201208291222
201208291222
201209300242
201209300242
201209300242
^D
      5 201208290101
      4 201208291222
      3 201209300242
```

Comment: thnaks cdhowie . you saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 1):

You can `awk` associative array:

```
 awk '{a[$0]++;} END{for(i in a) print i," = ", a[i]}' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

If everything is sorted, then

```
cat yourfile.txt | uniq -c
```

Otherwise, you need to sort it before you can use uniq:

```
cat yourfile.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: Why first `cat`? Useless here! +1 for the sort remark however

Comment: Good point.  It's my personal habit (albeit inefficient) to make things look consistent in scripts.  It's unnecessary here.

Comment: `cat` is more often misused, as it is meant to concatenate files ;)